# cocos2d space taken up on hard drive

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

How much space does coco2d take up for iphone development on the hard drive?  You have a limit of 20 megs for your application to download over wireless.  How much of this is going to be taken by cocos2d?

Comment: what size do you mean? that of the executable file, the application bundle or the ipa file (zipped)?

Comment: final product that gets put up on the app store.. i'm not 100% on what it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocos2d is a framework/set of frameworks that assists in the creation of 2d or 3d games. Similarly to any other framework, it shouldn't take up so much that it affects the download size of your app. It should barely be noticeable, and it won't push you over the 20 meg download limit.